# how to get String array in reverse order in Sqlite in android

Tags: android

```
 public String[] getAllDescription() {
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.query(NOTIFICATIONTABLE, new String[]{"notification_id", "notification_title",
                        "notification_description", "notification_isread", "date"}, null, null, null,
                null, null);

        String[] result = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        int i = 0;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                result[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("notification_description"));
                i++;
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        if ((cursor != null) && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

this is my code currently i am getting from 0 to n data in staring array i want to get in reverse array data from n to 0 so that i can Print please suggest me how i will get data

Comment: Why don't you try **order by** clause on date column?

Comment: where i should  apply that

Comment: Something like **cursor = db.query(NOTIFICATIONTABLE, new String[]{"notification_id", "notification_title",
                        "notification_description", "notification_isread", "date"}, null, null, null,
                null,  "date DESC");**

Comment: You can retrieve it by using the movetolast() ans movetoprevious() methods to retrieve the data before it added

Answer (score 1):

Try this method :

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllDescription()
{
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayListString>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * " + " FROM " + NOTIFICATIONTABLE+ " DESC;", null);
    res.moveToFirst();

    while (res.isAfterLast() == false)
    {

        array_list.add(hashmap);
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

Or If you want to reverse arrayList then you can also do it By just a single line of code .

```
Collections.reverse("yourArrayList");
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> i am getting from 0 to n data in staring array i want to get in
>   reverse array data from n to 0

Why not using `ASC` or `DESC` in db query to get result in sequence as want according to `notification_description` column.

do it as:

```
 cursor = db.query(NOTIFICATIONTABLE, 
                    new String[]{"notification_id", 
                                 "notification_title",
                                 "notification_description", 
                                 "notification_isread",
                                 "date"}, null, null, null,
                                 null, "notification_description DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the data from end of the`String[]`...

```
public String[] getAllDescription() {
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db.query(NOTIFICATIONTABLE, new String[]{"notification_id", "notification_title",
                    "notification_description", "notification_isread", "date"}, null, null, null,
            null, null);

    String[] result = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    int i = 0;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            ///////////////////////

            result[(cursor.getCount()-1)-i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("notification_description"));

            ///////////////////////

            i++;
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if ((cursor != null) && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```